# Solution to parabolic PDE with drift

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, parabolic-pde

Let $\Omega_x:= (-\infty,\infty)$ and $\Omega_t:= [0,\infty)$ be the domains respect the spatial $x$ and time $t$ variable. I'm trying to solve the following partial differential equation for $u:\Omega_x\times\Omega_t\to \mathbb{R}$
$$\frac{\partial\,u(x,t)}{\partial\,t} = f(x)\left( \frac{\partial^2\,u(x,t)}{\partial\,x^2} - \frac{\partial\,u(x,t)}{\partial\,x} \right),$$
with boundary conditions $u(x,0) = g(x)$, $u(0,t) = 0$. Where $f\in C^\infty(\Omega_x)$ monotonic increasing and $g \in C(\Omega_x)$ non decreasing (Not necessarily smooth).

Many thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far??

Comment: exponential shifting by a function, Fourier Transform, characteristic curves. None of them seemed to help much.

Comment: I don't think we can really say much about $u$ as long as $f$ is left arbitrary.